# OpenGL fragment shader in a texture

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have a simple RGBA texture that I will project on a rectangle/quad in OpenGL.

However, I want to do some operations in the rgb pixels of that texture, e.g., I want the displayed color to be some function of the RGB pixels of the original image.

My questions are: can I apply a fragment shader to a 2D texture? And if I can, How do I access the rgb value of the original texture image?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do this.  Render the quad as usual and send the texture to the fragment shader as a `sampler2D` uniform.

Inside the fragment shader, you can then make calls to either `texture` or `texelFetch`.  `texture` samples your texture, and `texelFetch` looks up an RGB texel from the texture without performing interpolation, etc.

Here is an example of what your fragment shader might look like:

**Fragment shader**

```
#version 330 core

uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform sampler2D myTexture;

out vec3 color;

void main()
{
    vec2 pos = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;
    pos.y = resolution.y - pos.y;

    color = texture(myTexture, pos).xyz;
}
```

And then on the application side:

**Initialization**

```
glGenTextures(1, &m_textureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textureID);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, m_imageWidth, m_imageHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pImage);

m_textureUniformID = glGetUniformLocation(m_programID, "myTexture");
```

**Render loop**

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textureID);
glUniform1i(m_textureUniformID, 0);
```